# Do you know of a reference for Aitken's graphical construction of points on a Parabola?

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, numerical-methods, graphing-functions, interpolation

I have been using Aitken's construction in my work. I have seen several references to the construction but never a direct reference to an article in a Journal.
I am preparing a comprehensive report to show the direct equivalence of the construction to the second-order Lagrange polynomial.
I will be including an extension of the construction that generates the local slopes at points on the parabola.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find my answer.
https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/proceedings-of-the-edinburgh-mathematical-society/article/on-interpolation-by-iteration-of-proportional-parts-without-the-use-of-differences/482BBF2A12045CB996628BE8C5B42FFC

Aitken, A. (1932). On Interpolation by Iteration of Proportional Parts, without the Use of Differences. Proceedings of the Edinburgh Mathematical Society, 3(1), 56-76. doi:10.1017/S0013091500013808

Regards
Alfred
Here are more details about Aitken's Construction.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hhtos2l85wa0qfr/Aitken%E2%80%99s%20Graphical%20Construction%20for%20a%20Parabola%20V4.pdf?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/iv6d52uymu3xslv/Step%20by%20Step%20%20Aitken%20Construction.pdf?dl=0